# Mongoose: Ensuring array is never larger than a certain number of items

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Trying to figure out the exact syntax for a `set` operation in Mongoose. I have a schema that looks like this:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  instagram: {
    images: [{
      id: { type: String },
      media_type: { type: String },
      media_url: { type: String },
      timestamp: { type: Date }
    }]
  }
});
```

I will periodically update this array with the user's latest Instagram photos like so:

`User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id }, { $addToSet: { "instagram.images": { $each: arr } } });`

How can I make sure the array is updated with the latest images, but never exceeds 30 images? The functionality should be that if the array has 20 images, and there are 11 new images to add, then all 11 new images should be added to the array and the last item that currently exists in the array should be removed.

Comment: if one of the answers was helpful, could you please mark the question as resolved or at least upvote them?

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve this with `$addToSet` operator. You have 2 options:

1. Make sure you're only fetching unique images, you can then achieve this using `$push` combined with the [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/) operator.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id }, 
    { $push: { "instagram.images": { $each: arr, $slice: -30 } } });
```

2. If you can't ensure unique images you'll have to fetch the user and filter the array in code before proceeding to update:

```
let user = User.findOne({_id});
// whatever unique indentifier makes an image "unqiue"
let imagesIds = user.instagram.images.map(v => v.id);
let fileterdImages = arr.filter((elem => !imagesIds.includes(elem.id)));
```

And finally using the syntax from option 1 with `fileterdImages`:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id }, 
    { $push: { "instagram.images": { $each: fileterdImages, $slice: -30 } } });
```

Note that mongoose tends to auto-generate an `_id` field for nested objects making the `$addToSet` not so relevant to begin with.

Comment: This is all under the assumptions images were pushed in chronological order. otherwise you'll have to do all the logic in code everytime.

Comment: Thanks for this thorough answer! I'm gonna go with your first solution. FYI, I also have `_id: false` in my nested obj, but didn't include it for simplicity, although I probably should have to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your logic right, try [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) operator, like this:

```
const T = async () => {
  try {
     //The result document won't be found, if array_field have more then 30 elements.
     let result = User.findOneAndUpdate({$expr: {$lte: [{$size: "$array_field"}, 30]}});
     if (!result) {
        //No such documents
     } else {
       //you could add as much elements as you want via for loop for example
       result.array_field.addToSet(element)
       //also you could check your array_field.length after it, before saving
       await result.save()
     }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

So if you `array_field` is less then 30 elements, it would be found, and so will be updated. You could also combine `$size` with [comparison operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/): `$gte` / `$lte`

`$addToSet` guarantees you, that you updated array with the unique values. So you could check it once more (if you want it to) before saving to the collection.